# Grundwortschatz für ein Lexikon (Flörsheimer Mundart)

Tags: vocabulary

Wir sind dabei, ein auf Mediawiki basierendes Lexikon des "[Flerschemerisch](http://www.flerschemerisch.de)", die zum Südhessischen gehörende Mundart wie sie in Flörsheim am Main gesprochen wird, zu erstellen.

Dabei liegt das Interesse bei diesem Projekt entgegen vieler anderer Mundartsammlungen hauptsächlich auf der Zusammenstellung eines [Grundwortschatzes](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundwortschatz), also einer Liste der am häufigsten gebrauchten Worte mit einem Umfang einiger weniger tausend Worte.

Bislang konnte ich in diesem Bereich noch nichts Brauchbares online finden, entweder sind die Zusammenstellungen zu klein oder beherbergen ein vollwertiges Lexikon. Kennt jemand eine Seite, die uns als Grundlage zur Vervollständigung dienen könnte?

Comment: Ist auf der angegebenen Seite zu sehen, "wir" sind im wesentlichen 3 Personen, die dieses Projekt initiiert haben und mit Leben füllen - aber ich wollte hier gar keine Werbung dafür machen, sondern nur den Kontext erklären, für was wir einen "Grundwortschatz" benötigen.

Answer (score 1):

Hilft die [Zusammenstellung der Uni Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/html/wliste.html) weiter?

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_h%C3%A4ufigsten_W%C3%B6rter_der_deutschen_Sprache) hat auch einen Artikel dazu mit weiterführenden Links.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis, das hilft schon weiter. Allerdings ist die Zusammenstellung etwas eigenwillig, da soch einige Wörter sicher nicht im Sinne eines Basiswortschatzes zu sehen sind und außerdem Groß-/Kleinschreibung mit berücksichtigt wird, was wahrscheinlich von schlichtem automatischen Extrahieren aus Texten und Zählen der Häufigkeit herrührt.